# angular ng-model is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

Template:

```
<select id="siteOptions" ng-model="siteVal" ng-change="siteChange()">
     <option ng-repeat = "site in sites" ng-selected="{{site == selectedSite}}"   value="site">{{site}}</option>
 </select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.siteChange = function(){
        console.log(" $scope.siteVal--> "+ $scope.siteVal);
}
```

I could able to populate values in dropdown properly, but when I try to select value in dropdown I could see "$scope.siteVal--> undefined".
 Even when I select the dropdown value multiple time ng-change is triggering only once.

Comment: Your code is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.value` attribute from your html markup and your code would work fine!

```
<select id="siteOptions" ng-model="siteVal" ng-change="siteChange()">
     <option ng-repeat = "site in sites" ng-selected="{{site == selectedSite}}">{{site}}</option>
</select>
```

From the [*DOCS*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected option

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ub9Toqr3u1ecZcRehBaa?p=preview) which demonstrates the same

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, after removing value from html I can access the selected option inside ng-model .

Comment: your answer is really helpful. Thank U Dhaval.